# Sharepoint navigation stops working with this script embeded into the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint

I am making tabs that change when clicked using Jquery and before and after CSS. When embedded into the SharePoint page the links on the navigation stop working. Everything else works on the page except for the navigation links to the other pages.

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function() {
   $("li").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("li").removeClass("selected");
     $(this).addClass("selected");
   });
  });
 </script>
```

```css
<style>
  .tabrow {
      text-align: center;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 50px 0 36px;
      padding: 0;
      line-height: 24px;
      height: 26px;
      overflow: hidden;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: verdana;
      position: relative;
  }
  .tabrow li {
      border: 1px solid #AAA;
      background: #D1D1D1;
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
      background: linear-gradient(top, #ECECEC 50%, #D1D1D1 100%);
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 0;
      border-top-left-radius: 6px;
      border-top-right-radius: 6px;
      box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 0 1px 0 #FFF;
      text-shadow: 0 1px #FFF;
      margin: 0 -5px;
      padding: 0 20px;
  }
  .tabrow a {
     color: #555;
     text-decoration: none;
  }
  .tabrow li.selected {
      background: #FFF;
      color: #333;
      z-index: 2;
      border-bottom-color: #FFF;
  }
  .tabrow:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: " ";
      width: 100%;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA;
      z-index: 1;
  }
  .tabrow li:before,
  .tabrow li:after {
      border: 1px solid #AAA;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -1px;
      width: 5px;
      height: 5px;
      content: " ";
  }
  .tabrow li:before {
      left: -6px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
      border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #D1D1D1;
  }
  .tabrow li:after {
      right: -6px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
      border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
      box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #D1D1D1;
  }
  .tabrow li.selected:before {
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #FFF;
  }
  .tabrow li.selected:after {
      box-shadow: -2px 2px 0 #FFF;
  }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are effectively changing the onclick behavior of every `<li>` element on your sharepoint page with your javascript. 
Try to be more specific with your jQuery selector. For example like this:

```
        $(".tabrow li").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).clostest(".tabrow").find("li").removeClass("selected");
          $(this).addClass("selected");
        });
```

Also you might experience problems on production environments, please enclose your jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".tabrow li").click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $(this).clostest(".tabrow").find("li").removeClass("selected");
              $(this).addClass("selected");
            });
});
```

This will execute the code, when page is finished loading (not only when code is reached).

Comment: After attempting to make the Jquery more specific it broke the whole process. I'm really new to working with Jquery so thank you in advance.

Comment: After working with the function I just relized I didn't wrap it in $(function() {